# How to write a specific url for only single page in wordpress?

Tags: plugins

I want to apply a custom url to only specific page like sitename/pagename to sitename/index.php/pagename.

This type i want only to this page only, how to do that ?

Comment: All other page will be in the same manner like sitename/pagename

Comment: You'd probably use htaccess.

Comment: How to rwrite url for this specific page in .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Custom permalinks and then you can set the URL of any page as you want.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: But when changin url using this like sitename/pagename to sitename/index.php/pagename
the page is accessible with both the url, that should not happened ?